# Как задать junit для surefire

Tags: maven, junit

У меня в зависимостях(подзависимости других зависимостей) проекта лежит testng, я подключил surefire для запуска тестов.

Как мне вместо testng использовать для тестирования junit?

Comment: Точно так же - подключить junit(но убрать testng сначало)

Comment: Убрать нельзя testng